# The operator < is not defined for the type Future<double>

Tags: list, flutter, maps, distance, provider

I am trying to calculate the distance and then display only carpools less than 3KM range. I am getting this issue while comparing the nearbylist with less than 3.

```
nearby(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) async {
      double total;
      total = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2);
      return total;
    }

    final nearbylist = availablecarpools.where((element) {
          return nearby(element.lat, element.lng, lat, lng) < 3;
        }).toList() ??
        [];
```

Comment: Add function prototype for nearby()

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the function `nearby()` returns a `Future`. You need wait for the Future and do the < 3 comparison.